# Ignore capitalization of letters set through JsonPropertyAttribute

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

I have a class with three simple properties:

```cs
public class NewCard {
    [JsonProperty( "name" )]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( "desc" )]
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( "idList" )]
    public string IdList { get; set; }
}
```

I expected a result like this:

```js
{"name":"A name","desc":"","idList":"listId"}
```

Unfortunately, the result I get looks like this:

```js
{"Name":"A name","Desc":"","IdList":"listId"}
```

The remote service rejects the json, so I really need to have them lowered. JSON.NET Version: 4.5.6 downloaded using NuGET.

Comment: What does your serialization code look like?

Comment: Sorry my fault. The library I'm started working with actually uses two different serializers. The call I tried picks not JSON.NET. Haven't seen this. Changed and works. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the result as you expect when I serialize as

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NewCard() {Name="A Name",Desc="A Desc",IdList="ids" });
```

Comment: Sorry my fault. The library I'm started working with actually uses two different serializers. The call I tried picks not JSON.NET. Haven't seen this. Changed and works. :(